# how to fix scroll down issue in selenium its tiktok bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I'm using - Python selenium and I'm new to it the problem is when ever i run the scroll code and the follow code to together the scroll code starts to scroll up suddenly and stop working.

This is my code:

```
N = 100
for i in range(N):
time.sleep(3)
#here is the line ############
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform()  
sleep(randint(3,4))  
follow = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//\*\[@id="main-content-homepage_hot"\]/div\[1\]/div\[1\]/div/div\[1\]/button').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def scroll_page(driver) -> None:


    # Scroll down the page
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    # Wait for some time to allow the page to load
    time.sleep(3)
```

Where **driver** - is chrome driver created before.